# Reversing a Doubly Linked List Code Not Working

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to solve [this question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reverse-a-doubly-linked-list/1), where we have to reverse a doubly linked list. I have written the following function for that purpose

```
Node* reverseDLL(Node * head)
{
    Node *curr=head;
    Node *prev=curr->prev;
    
    Node *next;
    
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        next=curr->next;
        curr->next=prev;
        curr->prev=curr->next;
        prev=curr;
        curr=next;
    }
    head=prev;
    return head;
}
```

But according to the online judge, it is showing that the answer is not correct, though when I am checking the logic on pen and paper the answer seems to be perfectly fine. Can anyone help me with where I am going wrong?

The code runs perfectly fine on C language though

[image]

Then why am I getting errors in CPP?

EDIT--> Found out the mistake in CPP,

```
while(curr!=NULL)
        {
            next=curr->next;
            curr->next=prev;
            curr->prev=next    //curr->prev=curr->next,  this was wrong
            prev=curr;
            curr=next;
        }
```

But now my question is how comes it runs fine in C language?

Comment: This is simply not the right logic, that's all. The best way to figure out how to do it is to take a paper and a pencil, then draw the diagram of the linked list, using arrows to represent pointers, then work out how the pointers need to change, then translate what you've done directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Ya found it out, this line should be `curr->prev=next`, but why was more doubtful is that the code ran perfectly on C language. U have any idea why? 
I have added an SS where the code runs fine in C language

Comment: I don't know what "the code ran perfectly on C language" means. The shown code will produce identical results whether compiled as C or C++. Pointers work exactly the same, in both languages.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik very true what u are saying, but have a look at the image that I have added. See that the code is same as the code which had error, though the online judge is showing that the ans its getting is correct. It is when I am using C compiler instead of C++

Comment: Some random "online judge" does not get to determine how C or C++ works. Perhaps that "online judge"'s checker for C programs is defective or buggy. You have no idea how that "online judge" works, and you have no guarantees, whatsoever, that its results are 100% correct all the time. This is why using some random "online judge" is not a productive way to learn C or C++.